# Debian 9: Backlight Flash at Boot

Tags: debian, boot, monitors, brightness

I've just installed a fresh new Debian 9 LXDE into an ACER AMD Notebook and everything seems to be working fine. However, during the boot, there is an annoying **Strong Backlight Flash** (seems like a photo flash). The sequence of events are basically as following:

- Boot starts at maximum backlight brightness
- Debian OS is selected at GRUB menu
- Some messages appear in low resolution at the command line
- **Strong Backlight Flash**
- Command line is now in high resolution
- Backlight Brightness is set to user pre-defined level
- LXDE login screen

Considering that during the Windows era of this notebook such flash never happened, I'm pretty sure there is a way via software to avoid that.

**Question**
How to avoid this **Strong Backlight Flash?**

---

**Debug**

```
root@debian:~# dmesg | grep -i "error\|firmware\|backlight"
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=740fe980-f018-4c49-b139-613d41d30fb9 ro quiet acpi_backlight=video
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=740fe980-f018-4c49-b139-613d41d30fb9 ro quiet acpi_backlight=video
[    0.294171] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.311772] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.057843] pci 0000:01:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
[    7.131791] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   12.551069] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/PALM_pfp.bin
[   12.685950] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/PALM_me.bin
[   12.705633] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
[   12.762705] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
[   13.481390] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
```

---

**Hardware Specifications**
[Notebook Aspire E1-421-0622](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4095) | [product details](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2013/4876/E1-421/NX.M25AL.004.html)

- AMD 2 Core™ Processor E1-1200 (1.4 GHz) 1MB Cache 64-bit Processing
- AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics Controller
- 2Gb DDR3 SDRAM Memory
- 256MB shared video memory

**Debian Strech**
[debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso)

- Software selection
  (  ) Debian desktop environment
  (  ) ... GNOME
  (  ) ... Xfce
  (  ) ... KDE
  (  ) ... Cinnamon
  (  ) ... MATE
  (X) ... LXDE
  (  ) web server
  (X) print server
  (  ) SSH server
  (X) standard system utilities
- Minor adjustments:

  - Non-free package `firmware-amd-graphics` installed ([full discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/8nz4pw/error_radeon_kernel_modesetting_for_r600/))
  - `/etc/default/grub` file updated ([full discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/8rfjpk/debian_9_backlight_brightness/)):

    ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=video"
    ```

Answer (score 1):

I felt unhappy about the same problem on my laptop maybe longer then this question stays open.

There is a solution:
**Disable backlight control** in [radeon driver](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#Linux_kernel_parameters) by adding `radeon.backlight=0` to kernel boot parameters.

But.
The problem here is that you might need another module to control the backlight. This means that instead of `acpi_backlight=video` you first should test your system with `acpi_backlight=vendor` or `acpi_backlight=native`.

More about backlight on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Kernel_command-line_options) and about ACPI video extensions in [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/video_extension.html).